# SwiftUI iOS16 - White space on Navigation Bar

Tags: swiftui, ios16

On iOS 16, I was trying to add an image to the toolbar to show it on the navigation bar, but i saw a white space in the status bar. I would like the image to start from the top and also not to hide the status bar.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

```
NavigationStack {
            List {
                Text("Hello World")
                Text("Hello World")
                Text("Hello World")
            }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                Image("header_top")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 112)
                    .scaledToFill()
            }

        }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: As I understand it, you can use `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` on your image

Comment: I did try that but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.offset()` but I think is not the best answer

```
NavigationStack {
            List {
                Text("Hello World")
                Text("Hello World")
                Text("Hello World")
            }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            
            .toolbar {
                Image("header_top")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 112)
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .background(.red)
                    .offset(y: -14)
            }
        }
```

result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the list specifically as a plain one:

```
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

I think since iOS 16 you can set the spacing to zero too, but I can not find it at the moment

Comment: A found it! try removing the default space by adding: .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()) to the list.